# Set a TextView's text from a JSON URL?

Tags: android, json, textview

Hello so i am currently making an app that gets json data from url and i want to get the "points" from the json set to textView7. I have some code but i do not know if its correct. I want to be able to pull 2 diffrent from the url https://www.lurkinator.net/api/data?username=bobtheshoplifter_

"points": 3, 
 "username": "bobtheshoplifter_"

I wanna set them both in the textView's i have

Here is how my text views look like [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxoFI.png) Both the username and points are seperate and the string of the username is @string/userid and points @string/points

```
    public class AddProfile extends Activity {
        // All xml labels

        TextView txtPoints;


        // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // Profile json object
        JSONArray points;
        JSONObject hay;
        // Profile JSON url
        private static final String POINTS_URL = "https://www.lurkinator.net/api/data?username=bobtheshoplifter_";

        // ALL JSON node names
        private static final String TAG_POINTS = "points";


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            txtPoints = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
```

Comment: try to learn **json parsing** in android, you can google it

Comment: Post rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

The call to the link is asynchronous and the data will not be available immediately once the activity is opened so you have to ensure you have mechanism to call setText on the textview once the data is retrieved from the network call.

1. Volley(or any other equivalent to manage network request)
2. A callback to the activity to set the retrieved text in the textview once you have obtained the data.

**Volley** - 
Go to this [link](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/networking/android-volley-tutorial/) to know more about volley and how to set it up.

**Callback** - 
Create an interface `Callback` as below. The method updateData should be invoked once you have retrieved the data from the network call.

```
public interface Callback{
    public void updateData(String data);
}
```

Now implement this interface as below in the `Activity` class

```
public class AddProfile extends Activity implements Callback{
```

Now you have to implement the method `updateData` in the `AddProfile` class

```
public void updateData(String data){
      txtPoints.setText(data);
}
```

Now you have to add code to invoke the url, parse the data and call the callback to set the points.

In the `AddProfile` class add the code:

```
txtPoints = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, POINTS_URL, new Response.Listener<String>(){

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                String data=object.getString(TAG_POINTS);
                this.updateData(data);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //add any error handling
        }
    });

Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(request);
```

Above code invokes the url and parses the JSON and retrieves the points. After the points is retrieved it invokes the method `updateData` where you have the code to set the data in the textview.

Suggested reading the tutorial [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm) for working with JSON in android.